Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'plan_apply': Matrix must define at least one vector
I have a workflow that is supposed to pass value using Matrix to another composite workflow. I am able to validate that the matrix is good. But I am running into this error "Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'plan_apply'. .github/workflows/actions.yml (Line: 102, Col: 9): Matrix must define at least one vector", and plan_apply job does not run
actions.yml
name: Terraform Workflow

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - github-terraform-plan
      - github-terraform-apply
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read
  id-token: write
  pull-requests: read

jobs:
  filter:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
      - name: Check out the repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Set Matrix Based on Changes
        id: set-matrix
        run: |
          echo "Setting up matrix with filter checks"
          matrix=$(jq -n '[]')

          # Check if the accounts-workdir.txt file exists
          if [[ ! -f .github/accounts-workdir.txt ]]; then
            echo "File .github/accounts-workdir.txt not found!"
            exit 1
          fi

          # Initialize arrays for accounts and directories
          accounts=()
          directories=()

          # Read each line in the file and extract account ID and directory
          while IFS=' ' read -r _ account directory; do
            accounts+=("$account")
            directories+=("$directory")
          done < .github/accounts-workdir.txt

          # Iterate over accounts and directories to detect changes
          for i in "${!accounts[@]}"; do
            account="${accounts[i]}"
            dir="${directories[i]}"
            base_ref="HEAD^"
            echo "Checking for changes in $dir relative to $base_ref..."
            result=$(git diff --quiet --exit-code "$base_ref"...HEAD -- "$dir" && echo false || echo true)

            if [[ $result == "true" ]]; then
              echo "Changes detected in $dir for account $account."
              matrix=$(echo "$matrix" | jq --arg account "$account" --arg work_dir "$dir" '. + [{"account_id": $account, "work_dir": $work_dir}]')
            else
              echo "No changes detected in $dir for account $account."
            fi
          done

          # Convert JSON to a single-line format for environment compatibility
          matrix=$(echo "$matrix" | jq -c .)
          echo "Final Matrix: $matrix"

          # Set the matrix as an output
          echo "::set-output name=matrix::$matrix"

          echo "matrix=$matrix" >> $GITHUB_ENV

  validate_matrix:
    needs: filter
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      validated_matrix: ${{ steps.validate.outputs.validated_matrix }}
    steps:
      - name: Validate Matrix Structure
        id: validate
        run: |
          matrix="${{ needs.filter.outputs.matrix }}"
          echo "Matrix output for validation: $matrix"

          # Check if matrix is empty or valid JSON array
          if [[ -z "$matrix" || "$matrix" == "[]" ]]; then
            echo "Matrix is empty or invalid. Defaulting to an empty array."
            validated_matrix="[]"
          else
            echo "Matrix is valid JSON: $matrix"
            validated_matrix="$matrix"
          fi

          # Output validated matrix using environment files
          echo "validated_matrix=$validated_matrix" >> $GITHUB_ENV

  plan_apply:
    needs: validate_matrix
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        include: ${{ fromJson(needs.validate_matrix.outputs.validated_matrix || '[]') }}
      fail-fast: false
    steps:
    - name: Debug Matrix
      run: |
        echo "Matrix: ${{ toJson(matrix) }}"
 
    - name: Check out the repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
      with:
         fetch-depth: 0

    - name: Debug Matrix Value in plan_apply
      run: |
        echo "Validated matrix passed to plan_apply:"
        echo "${{ needs.validate_matrix.outputs.validated_matrix }}"

    - name: Run Terraform Plan for Account ${{ matrix.account_id }}
      if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/github-terraform-plan' }}
      uses: ./.github/workflows/terraform-plan
      with:
        AWS_REGION: us-east-2
        OIDC_IAM_ROLE_ARN: arn:aws:iam::009160066642:role/AssumeRoleWithAction
        ACCOUNT_ID: ${{ matrix.account_id }}
        WORK_DIR: ${{ matrix.work_dir }}
        IAM_ROLE_NAME: TerraformDeploymentAssumeRoleWithAction

    - name: Run Terraform Apply for Account ${{ matrix.account_id }}
      if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/github-terraform-apply' }}
      uses: ./.github/workflows/terraform-apply
      with:
        AWS_REGION: us-east-2
        OIDC_IAM_ROLE_ARN: arn:aws:iam::009160066642:role/AssumeRoleWithAction
        ACCOUNT_ID: ${{ matrix.account_id }}
        WORK_DIR: ${{ matrix.work_dir }}
        IAM_ROLE_NAME: TerraformDeploymentAssumeRoleWithAction


composite workflow
# action.yml as a Composite Action
name: "Terraform Plan Composite Action"
description: "Executes Terraform Init & Plan using provided AWS credentials and directory inputs"

inputs:
  AWS_REGION:
    required: true
    description: "AWS Region"
  OIDC_IAM_ROLE_ARN:
    required: true
    description: "OIDC Role ARN to assume"
  ACCOUNT_ID:
    required: true
    description: "AWS Account ID"
  WORK_DIR:
    required: true
    description: "Directory for Terraform commands"
  IAM_ROLE_NAME:
    required: true
    description: "IAM Role name to assume within the account"


runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0

    - name: Configure AWS credentials using OIDC
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
      with:
        role-to-assume: ${{ inputs.OIDC_IAM_ROLE_ARN }}
        aws-region: ${{ inputs.AWS_REGION }}
        role-session-name: Terraform

    - name: Set up AWS CLI
      shell: bash  # Explicitly specify shell
      run: |
        sudo apt-get install -y awscli
        aws --version

    - name: Set up Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
      with:
        terraform_version: 1.9.5

    - name: Debug Role ARN
      shell: bash
      run: |
        ROLE_ARN="arn:aws:iam::${{ inputs.ACCOUNT_ID }}:role/${{ inputs.IAM_ROLE_NAME }}"
        echo "IAM_ROLE_NAME=${{inputs.IAM_ROLE_NAME}} and ROLE_ARN=${ROLE_ARN}"

    - name: Assume IAM role and run Terraform
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo "Running Terraform for AWS Account: ${{ inputs.ACCOUNT_ID }} in directory ${{ inputs.WORK_DIR }}"
        
        cd "${{ inputs.WORK_DIR }}" || { echo "Failed to change directory to ${{ inputs.WORK_DIR }}"; exit 1; }

        ROLE_ARN="arn:aws:iam::${{ inputs.ACCOUNT_ID }}:role/${{ inputs.IAM_ROLE_NAME }}"
        CREDENTIALS=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "$ROLE_ARN" --role-session-name github-actions-session)

        export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')
        export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')
        export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo $CREDENTIALS | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken')

        terraform init
        terraform plan

    # Optionally include Terraform apply if it's not conditional on external events
    # Note: Conditional steps need to be handled externally from this composite action


Error:
Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'plan_apply'. .github/workflows/actions.yml (Line: 102, Col: 9): Matrix must define at least one vector
How can I resolve this error?
I was expecting the matrix value passed on to the composite workflow. Output of the matrix below
Matrix output for validation: [{account_id:999999999999,work_dir:terraform/environments/test/us-east-2/}]
Matrix is valid JSON: [{account_id:999999999999,work_dir:terraform/environments/test/us-east-2/}]

That's not valid JSON. See here.

Was the error "Matrix must define at least one vector" generated for above JSON or for []?
